# Posgtresql pgadmin how to prevent access to schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm new on PostgreSQL. I created a user for to use a specific schema. I have done a table but I can't prevent on schema. I don't want to show all schema to the user. How can I prevent to access the schema?

Answer (score 0):

[Grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) and [Revoke](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) to grant access and privileges on your database, including schema.